# for (Object o : Objects) разве не должен дать ссылку на объект? Java

Tags: java

Хочу заполнить созданный массив:

```
Object[] objects = new Object[10];
for (Object obj : objects){
    obj = new Object();
}
```

Android Studio пишет, что переменная `obj` нигде не используется, разве цикл не должен дать ссылку на объект?

Comment: Он вам её даёт, а вы её тут же затираете ссылкой, которую вернул оператор `new`.

Comment: я и хочу ее затереть а она не затирается, ссылка readOnly что ли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде всего важно заметить, что циклы foreach предназначены для обхода последовательности без её изменения. Если вам нужно изменять итерируемую последовательность, придётся использовать или обычный for и доступ по индексу или for с явным итератором.

Чтобы понять происходящее, нужно осознать, что ячейка массива и переменная цикла - это две разных переменных, даже если содержат одно и то же значение. Предположим, что `objects[0]` содержит значение 0x123456789, которое является адресом некого объекта. На первой итерации это значение присваивается переменной цикла. В теле цикла вы переменной цикла присваиваете новое значение - предположим, 0x987654321. Теперь переменная цикла ссылается на новый объект, но ячейка массива всё ещё ссылается на старый.